# How many lines get allocated to "intro to a question" under Questions tab?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I was surprised to see  more lines than usual allocated to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233659/how-to-compute-this-summation-composite-function). How does that happen?

Comment: My guess is that it is the number of characters, and not number of lines that makes the difference.

Comment: Are you talking about $f(10)=\{0,2,4,6,8,10\}$ being put on a line by itself? I am not sure what you mean by "allocated lines".

Comment: To see better what the OP means, you can look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summation?sort=active&pagesize=50) (at least until the questions is pushed from the front page in that tag).

Comment: I see now, it goes by the count of characters. Is there a way of knowing how much of a question will be displayed before submitting it?  If not, what is the number of characters that will show in the Questions tab?

Comment: Possibly related http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one Well, that's posting multiple questions as one and this one question was posted multiple times so it's not exactly the same thing.  See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6540/the-portion-of-a-question-that-will-display-under-the-questions-tab

Answer (score 3):

The question "summary" (displayed in line in some places, and in tooltips in others) is character count based, not line based.

This is by design.

Comment: Willie Wong mentioned a similar idea too. Do you know how many characters? This comment box counts my characters and lets me know how many I have left. But somehow the same feature is not available when posing a question. Not a big issue but I was wondering. I guess I just count the characters that got displayed (including the TeX command characters).